# Outlook attachment (associated file extension) cannot open in my program due to "access denied"

Tags: c#, wpf, access-denied, file-association

I have a C# (WPF) app which opens automatically if you double click its data file within Windows. The file association is registered with Windows so it knows to open the app and load the file (via args[]). This all works fine.

Problem:
If one of the data files is emailed within outlook, when you double click the attached file to open it, it does launch the associated c# program correctly. However the app can't open the file path passed through args[] since it is a temporary outlook folder location. The C# program tries to open it but understandably gets 'access denied' to that path outlook creates.

Since I know you can open PDF, office documents and images from attachments there must be a way to do this but I can't determine how and searches aren't working. Any suggestions where to look?

Below is the code the args come in and the eventual attempt to open the file:

```
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1) 
        { 
             ApplicationWorkspace.Instance.ViewModel.ProcessFile(args[1]);
        }

    public SessionModel Read(string path)
    {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SessionModel));
            SessionModel session=null;

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(path, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry("SessionData.xml");
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        session = (SessionModel)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

                    }
                }
            }

            return session;
```

}

Access to the path 'C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\NetCache\Content.Outlook\LVXFKZW9\<filename.fileExtension> is denied.

Comment: I hate being asked to be a psychic, especially on Christmas Eve. My assumption is that the file is already in use by Outlook, but without code who knows?

Comment: `However the app can't open the file path passed through args[] since it is a temporary outlook folder location` Temporary or not is irrelevant. If the file is there, your app can access it.

Comment: `The C# program tries to open it but understandably gets 'access denied' to that path outlook creates.` What is the **exact** path to the temporary file? **Do not guess**.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking for some theory I may be missing; the code works but the program has no access to the path passed by outlook; whether it is locked, etc. Since other applications do it, I thought there was a special method I should be using. I will update with existing code and path with error msg. (it wasn't Christmas eve here yet :)

Comment: Does your username have a space in it? Does `filename.fileExtension` have a space in it?

Comment: @mjwills no spaces in username or filename/extension. I am creating a new build to log out all the args passed from outlook

Comment: If you go to that path and double click on the file there does it work?

Comment: @mjwills It doesn't. The file was hard to find...I had to disable 'Hide OS level files' before I could find it in file explorer. I seem to have access to the file to open it in notepad, etc., but the C# app does not have access. Must be permissions around the app itself or perhaps the Open() function since this is a secure folder outlook creates. No idea how to address it, but gives me some clues...thanks

Comment: Is the file marked as "read only"? If so, that likely explains what you are seeing since you are opening it for _updating_.

Comment: @mjwills It is. nice catch. Attachments likely open in protected mode. thank you for your help - it help me learn what was happening. Happy holidays!